# How can I model the Circle packing problem with pyomo?

Tags: geometry, pyomo, packing

Circle packing problem in a circle container with minimal radius

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these [strip packing examples](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/master/examples/gdp/strip_packing). The circle packing problem will be similar.